# Difference between NSThread and detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:

Tags: cocoa, nsthread

In the NSThread documentation, I came across the method `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`.
What's the difference between that method and creating a thread with `initWithTarget:selector:object:` and then starting it with `start`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that the second way gives you a reference to the NSThread object, so you can do things like set the stack size or priority before starting it, or use the isExecuting/Finished/Cancelled methods to check its status later.